# How do I add multiple tags or keywords in Lightroom using a preset?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, photo-management, tagging, keywords

I want to add a set of keywords for certain types of photos - typically for a certain flower I want to add as keywords its scientific name, its vernacular name, and the tagד "flower" and "flowers". As I take photos of this flower routinely and regularly I want to have the option with one click of a button to add all those keywords at once, where still they will be treated as separate keywords (e.g. for Flickr). How do I define such keyword sets presets in Lightroom Classic?

I tried using the option "Keyword Set" but when adding multiple tags it treats them as one long tag instead of separate tags.

In the Adobe Bridge CS5 there was such an option by using "append metadata" and in that preset metadata write the desired keywords and tags, separating them with ";". I think the trick could work also in Lightroom, so how do I append metadata from a preset?